# Wrong currency Format for United States

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list

We currently face the issue in our **SP2013** Environment, that we have a wrong currency format for United States:

[image]

This picture is taken from trying to change the currency format of a List column. First the currency is wrong, second the format is wrong. We have not manually changed the currency format. The regional settings for this site are set on English (United States).

Does anyone know where this wrong format could come from?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem was, that a server image was used, where values in the registry for US format were changed.

After setting the correct format in the registry for every Service Account (SID) under:

[HKEY_USERS\ **[SID]** \Control Panel\International]

The correct format is now being displayed.